# ggplot2 histogram showing proportion of group by bin instead of count

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Assuming a dataset made of two groups:

```
dataA<-rnorm(200,3,sd=2)
dataB<-rnorm(500,5,sd=3)
all<-data.frame(dataset=c(rep('A',length(dataA)),rep('B',length(dataB))),value=c(dataA,dataB))
```

We can plot the histogram with the two groups like this:

```
ggplot(all,aes(value,fill=dataset))+geom_histogram(bins=50,position='stack')
```

I would like to obtain the same kind of plot but with the **proportion of each group instead of the count for every bin**.

I found the following way to do it by calculating the proportion manually for each group:

```
ggplot(all,aes(x=value,fill=dataset))+geom_histogram(aes(y=c(..count..[..group..==1]/(..count..[..group..==1]+..count..[..group..==2]),..count..[..group..==2]/(..count..[..group..==1]+..count..[..group..==2]))),position='stack',bins=50)+ylab('proportion')
```

This gives the expected result (below), but it's a very inelegant solution. I'm probably missing something here, is there a better way to obtain the same (or a similar) result?

[image]

Comment: You might be looking for `position = "fill"`.

Comment: @teunbrand Yes, thank you! I knew there must be a better way, this is indeed what I was missing. If you want to write an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for `position = 'fill'` instead of `'stack'`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(42)

dataA <- rnorm(200, 3, sd = 2)
dataB <- rnorm(500, 5, sd = 3)

all <- data.frame(
  dataset = c(rep('A', length(dataA)),rep('B', length(dataB))),
  value   = c(dataA, dataB)
)

ggplot(all, aes(value, fill = dataset)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 50, position = 'fill')
#> Warning: Removed 14 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(ggplot2) 
library(scales)
  
dataA<-rnorm(200,3,sd=2)
dataB<-rnorm(500,5,sd=3)
all<-data.frame(dataset=c(rep('A',length(dataA)),rep('B',length(dataB))),value=c(dataA,dataB))  
  
ggplot(all, aes(value, fill = dataset)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(count / sum(count)))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood.